# Chaining Promises with Failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Looking at this [blog](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/04/angularjspart-11-promises/)'s post handling of promises, I modified the failure example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($q, $scope) {

    (function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        promise.then(function(result) {
            console.log("success pass 1 - " + result);
            return result;
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log("failure pass 1, reason:", reason);
            throw new Error("failed with: " + reason);
        }).
        then(function(result) {
            console.log("2nd success! result: ", result);
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log("2nd failure! reason: ", reason);
        });


        console.log("calling deferred.reject('bad luck')");
        deferred.reject("bad luck");

    })();
```

For my first failure function, I noticed that replacing `throw` with `return` would result in:

```
calling deferred.reject('bad luck') 
failure pass 1, reason: bad luck 
2nd success! result:  Error {stack: (...), message: "failed with: bad luck"}
```

As a result, I replaced `return` with `throw` to achieve the desired `failure -> failure` result.

```
calling deferred.reject('bad luck') 
failure pass 1, reason: bad luck 
Error: failed with: bad luck at ...app.js
2nd failure! reason: Error {stack: ... "failed with: bad luck"}
```

The thrown error appears to not have been caught. Why is that? Shouldn't the inner failure case have caught this thrown error?

Also, in a chained promise, can a successive error case (in this case the 2nd chain promise's failure case) only be reached through the throwing of an `Error`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a design choice of `$q` which is very unorthodox in a sense.

A design decision was made in `$q` that `throw`s and `reject`s are treated differently since the library does not track unhandled rejections for you. This is to avoid the case where errors get swallowed:

```
JSNO.parse("{}"); // note the typo in JSON, in $q, since this is an error
                  // it always gets logged, even if you forgot a `.catch`.
                  // in Q this will get silently ignored unless you put a .done
                  // or a `catch` , bluebird will correctly track unhandled
                  // rejections for you so it's the best in both.
```

They get caught, handled but still logged.

In `$q`, rejections are used instead:

```
return $q.reject(new Error("failed with: " + reason));
```

Comment: Would not be `$q.reject(...)`, right? Wouldn't it be something like `deferred.reject(...)` where `deferred = $q.defer()`?

Comment: No, you only need deferreds when creating a new promise. I definitely meant `$q.reject` here

Comment: Ahh. I thought reject and resolve were only available on what was returned from defer. I'm curious about the use case for calling it on $q. Maybe I'll play around and write up a question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you may have found by now. If you want to chain promises with failure, only supply failure handler at end of the chain.

```
    promise.then(function(result) {
        console.log("success pass 1 - " + result);
        return result;
    } /* don't handle failure here. Otherwise, a
         new promise (created by 'then') wraps the
         return value (normally undefined) in a new
         promise, and it immediately solves it 
         (means success) since the return value of
         your failure handler is not a promise.

         leave failure handler empty, 'then' will pass
         the original promise to next stage if the
         original promise fails. */
    ).
    then(function(result) {
        console.log("2nd success! result: ", result);
    }, function(reason) {

        /* both 1st and 2nd failure can be captured here */

        console.log("1st or 2nd failure! reason: ", reason);
    });
```